# How to get Xpath in div tag?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have to get xxxxxxxx in this code using Selenium in python. How to get href or xxxxxxxxxxxxx and how to access target also ?

```
<div class="card-header bg-light card-collapse p-0" id="readHeading13">
<a class="btn btn-link btn-block text-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center py-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#readCollapse13" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="readCollapse13">13. owner <span class="accordion-arrow">
<i class="fas fa-arrow-down small">
</i>
</span>
</a>
</div>
<div id="readCollapse13" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="readHeading13"><div class="card-body p-3">
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<a href="/address/xxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_parent">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</a> <i><span class="text-monospace text-secondary">address</span></i></div></form></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the text value *`xxxxxxxxxxxxx`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.card-body > form a[href*='address']").text)
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'card-body')]/form//a[contains(@href, 'address')]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`::

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card-body > form a[href*='address']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute::

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='name' and @title='Download']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the unique locator here will be as following:

```py
//div[@class="form-group" and(contains(text(),"address"))]//a
```

So, to you can get the `href` attribute and the text values as following:

```py
el = driver.find-element_by_xpath('//div[@class="form-group" and(contains(text(),'address'))]//a')
el_href = el..get_attribute("href")
el_text = el.text
```